Apply Local Rotation after Transform
I am currently writing my thesis essentially about Camera Re-Localization using SfM. To compare results and measure them properly, I created a dataset with ground truth in Blender. It works as follows: A 3D scanned architecture model, around that circa 10 cameras, these cameras are my ground truth, they will be used as input in the SfM pipeline. The pipeline outputs camera poses in their own coordinate system. These poses will be compared to the ground truth poses in regards to rotation and translation error per pose (how far off the rotation and localtion is).
To compare them, I first need to normalize the estimated poses, so they are overlapping as good as possible. For this I am using a transform to align the estimated poses with the ground truth poses using scale, rotation and translation.
I then apply them and get a new position for the estimated poses. This works very well, BUT now the problem is that the local rotation is not applied, meaning the poses maintain their viewing direction (rotation) after the tranform. Due to this I cannot compare the rotation error, which is really annoying... Also I need this transform to work for a later process, so I definitely need this fixed...
As you can see in the images before and after alignment(highlighted=estimated camera poses), even though the locations after the transform are quite good, the rotation does not change, obviously be cause I never explicitly set it. I tried a few approaches to set the correct local rotation of each camera, but it did not work out yet...


This should probably be a question in a math forum. I rarely used this kind of math in my work, and now I need to use it again. And in addition I am quite bad as it seems. But If anybody is smarter than me and can solve this issue, I would be very happy. Here is my code so far:
 def helmert_transform(ground_truth_points, estimated_points):
    # Compute scale
    centered_gt = ground_truth_points - ground_truth_points[0]
    centered_est = estimated_points - estimated_points[0]
    scale = np.sqrt(np.sum(centered_gt**2) / np.sum(centered_est**2))
    print("Scale:", scale)

    # Compute rotation using SVD
    H = np.dot(centered_est.T, centered_gt)
    U, _, Vt = np.linalg.svd(H)
    rotation = np.dot(Vt.T, U.T)
    print("Initial Rotation Matrix:\n", rotation)

    # Ensure a proper rotation matrix (det(R) = 1)
    if np.linalg.det(rotation) < 0:
        Vt[-1, :] *= -1
        rotation = np.dot(Vt.T, U.T)
    print("Adjusted Rotation Matrix:\n", rotation)

    # Compute translation
    translation = ground_truth_points[0] - scale * np.dot(rotation, estimated_points[0])
    print("Translation:", translation)

    return scale, rotation, translation

# apply transform to a point
def apply_helmert_transform(point, scale, rotation, translation):
    # apply transform to receive new location of point
    transformed_point = scale * np.dot(point, rotation.T) + translation
    return transformed_point

# align estimated camera poses to ground truth poses
# top_cams = map of selected 3 poses for optimal transform calculation (containing ground truth 'c1' and estimated 'c2' camera poses mapped correctly)
# est_cams = all estimated camera poses to be aligned
def align_estimated_to_ground_truth(est_cams, top_cams):
    # Extract the top cameras' positions
    gt_positions = np.array([cam["c1"].location for cam in top_cams])
    est_positions = np.array([cam["c2"].location for cam in top_cams])

    # Compute the Helmert transformation
    scale, rotation, translation = helmert_transform(gt_positions, est_positions)

    # Apply the transformation to all estimated camera poses
    apply_to = est_cams
    for cam in apply_to:
        est_position = np.array(cam.location)
        transformed_position = apply_helmert_transform(
            est_position, scale, rotation, translation
        )
        cam.location = transformed_position


Ok I found it out myself! To get the local rotation you need to inverse the rotation matrix and apply it to the cameras location:
try:
    local_rot = Matrix(np.linalg.inv(rotation)).transposed().to_euler()
except np.linalg.LinAlgError as e:
    raise Exception(
        f"Failed to apply local rotation due to not inversible rotation matrix: {e}"
    )

Then in the cam transform loop:
cam.rotation_euler.rotate(local_rot)

